# Phonegap + Android + FCM & Health plugins

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

When I install cordova-plugin-health, everything works, but after installing cordova-plugin-fcm, build fails. Log below. I'm struggling with it since last week and now it is hard to find a Stack Overflow answer I haven't seen.

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.923 secs

Error: /Users/[...]/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider:

- Make sure you have your 'google-services.json' file in the root of your project directory (for cordova-plugin-fcm)
- Try updating your Android SDK platforms from the SDK manager
- Try removing the android platform from your project ("phonegap platform remove android"), and adding the newest version of android with "phonegap platform add android@latest"

The last point was the one that solved similar issues for me, since lower versions of the phonegap android have problems with the newest FCM/GCM libraries.

Comment: 'google-services.json' file present.
Android SDK updated.
Platform rm&add@latest done.

Still the same error.

Comment: What version of android are you using in phonegap? ie: phonegap plugin list

Comment: android 6.2.3, cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin", cordova-plugin-health 1.0.0 "Cordova Health"

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a version conflict in the Gradle configuration. 
`cordova-plugin-fcm` is requesting v9.0.0 of `com.google.android.gms` (Play Services library) but `cordova-plugin-health` is [requesting the most recent version](https://github.com/dariosalvi78/cordova-plugin-health/blob/master/plugin.xml#L81) ie. `+`, the [latest release](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) being v11.2.0.

As outlined in [this cordova-plugin-fcm issue](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/274) there is not a simple solution that works for all plugin conflicts: `cordova-plugin-fcm` is problematic because the version is [specified implicitly](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/blob/master/src/android/FCMPlugin.gradle#L13).

One solution you can try is to install [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release), specifying v9.0.0 for `PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION`:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=9.0.0
```